# a.toLowerCase when add CORS to the ajax header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-cors-headers

I have a Django app online and an API which requires to add special `token` into header.

When I add it to the `$.ajaxSetup` it still requires from me `CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin` param in header.

When I add it, I'm getting an error: `TypeError: a.toLowerCase is not a function`

The weird part is when I use the same code in my HttpRequester firefox plugin because I'm getting the proper response with expected data.

The code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader({
          'CORS': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
          'token': 'tokenStringHere'
        });
    }
});

$.ajax({
  url: 'myPathToOnlineAppWithApiString',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  headers: {
  }
}).success(function(result){
  console.log('yes!');
}).error(function(error){
  console.log('no!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setRequestHeader` accepts two strings, the header name and its value, not an object. See The [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) section of the `$.ajax` entry of the jQuery docs for more information.

You should replace the object in the parameter with two calls to set those headers individually:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('CORS', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('token', 'tokenStringHere');
    }
});
```

Comment: This put me one step further - thanks! (it turned out that an app has restricted all CORS access so I have to ask programmer who maintain it to open it for me) - btw. I'm so ashamed that it was in the documentation - but it's a lesson for me today to double-check it before asking questions.

Comment: No problem, glad to help